# webkit-animation-fill-mode is not working in firefox

Tags: css, css-animations

I have tried to implement a design like progress bar using  webkit animation fillmode but its not supporting in firefox.

I have tried some solution as changing %value to px but still it doesnt support.

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>

<style rel="stylesheet">
    #progressbar {
      background-color: #e3e5e6;
      border-radius: 8px;
      padding: 0px;
      width: 400px;
    }

    #progressbar div {
      background-color: #afd163;
      height: 10px;
      width:0%;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border-top-right-radius:0px;
      border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
      animation:loadbar 2s;
      -webkit-animation:loadbar 2s;
      -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes loadbar {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }
    100% {
        width: 100%;
    }

    @keyframes loadbar {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }
    100% {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="progressbar">
    <div></div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Sorry my mistake. Your problem is not vendor prefixes - it's a simple missing closing brace:

```
@-webkit-keyframes loadbar {
  0% {
     width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes loadbar {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

This will work ;) . Firefox does currently support the non-prefixed animation property.

Having said that, you might still want to look into using the other vendor prefixes to be safe - you can't guarantee that everyone is keeping their firefox or other browser up to date.